# Using libcurl with rtsp url

Tags: libcurl, rtsp

I'm writing a small utility to download video using rtsp url. I would like to know if it is possible
to directly download using libcurl given rtsp url.
I know that I can use ffmpeg to write directly to a video file. 
But I want to do this using libcurl.

Answer (score -1):

rtsp is a streaming protocol, there is nothing to dowload

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: There is no answer to the question because rtsp is a streaming protocol thus you can capture frames but you cannot download a stream.

Comment: Hi Michelle: I was suggesting that this is better left as a comment on the original post. With your > 50 rep you have the privilege of [commenting everywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment), so you can leave comments on the question.